# How to change the default path of view files in a sails?

Tags: sails.js

Perhaps i want to store my views in /pages directory.
Next code in configs of sails directory does not reinit views path:

```
  paths: {
    views: path.normalize(__dirname + '/../pages')
  }
```

but code for public dir works well:

```
  paths: {
    public: path.normalize(__dirname + '/../any_public_dir')
  }
```

What can i do?

Comment: Please be more specific, what is your purpose and what is your problems.

Comment: He means that the default views directory in Sails.js is `/views`, and he may want to change that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because of the way that Sails loads configuration, it's not currently possible to change the path for most things from within a file in the `config` folder.  You can, however, do it in the `.sailsrc` file:

```
{
  "paths": {
    "views": "../pages"
  }
}
```

Comment: thank you, i understand. but i thought that the configuration is initialized before the application starts

Comment: It is, but the paths are a special case because Sails needs to know the paths *before* loading all the rest of the configuration files.

Comment: apart from `"views"`, what other paths can be configured ? I tried `"api": "./build/api"` but doesn't work. Unfortunately I can't find any relevant documentation, even in the upcoming MEAP book.

Comment: Answer to my previous question is `paths: {"controllers": "./build/api/controllers", "policies": "./build/api/policies", "services": "./build/api/services", ...}` etc

Comment: Does anything change after sails 1? Is it possible now or not?

Answer (score 0):

If you do not use `sails lift`, but rather have your own app and lift from inside it:

```
var Sails = require('sails');
Sails.lift({}, function(err, server) {});
```

then you can specify the path there

```
var Sails = require('sails');
Sails.lift({
  //environment: 'test', // if you need to set 
  //hooks:{foo: false}, // if you want to disable some of them
  paths: { views: 'mydir/views' }, // relative to appDir
}, function(err, server) {});
```

You can later (in the sails controllers/services) get the current views dir:

```
var vdir = sails.config.paths.views;
```

To get other configurable pathes `console.log(Object.keys(sails.config));`